# Call date "input mask" after bootstrapDialogue loads

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal, input-mask, bootstrap-dialog

In my `form`, I am loading `form edit` using `BootstrapDialog`. My form contains some date fields and text fields. The date field is given a mask function which will always allow proper date format. In normal I call the mask function as below.

```
$("[data-mask]").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy"});
```

But this method does not work after i load my date field using `BootstrapDialog`. I think the inputmask function calls before the `BootstrapDialog`. How can I solve this issue?

**HTML Field**

```
<input type="text" style="  width: 75px"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-mask="" name="to_date" id="to_date"/>
```

`data-mask` is a custom attribute. Which works fine in page load

**Bootstrap Loading Function**

```
function popup_dialogue(title, message) {
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        title : title,
        message : message
    });
}
```

**Calling after ajax**

```
success: function(data){
            unloading();
            if(data.msg){
                popup_dialogue('title', data.msg);
                $("[data-mask]").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy"});
            }
            else if(data.error){
                alert(data.error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: why don't you keep `$("[data-mask]").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy"});` inside your `popup_dialogue` function?

Comment: I tried and it didn't give any result

Comment: Am not sure whether this `$("[data-mask]")` is a proper selector. Post some html too to understand..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, I added the html now

Comment: Try adding `$("[data-mask]").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy"});` within `setTimeout` like `setTimeout(function(){$("[data-mask]").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy"});},100);`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, I think it is not a proper solution. I already did it and it works.

Comment: see that's like assigning your masking task to a different thread in js.. Its up to you to opt it or not.. :)

Comment: could you please try putting `.inputmask` code inside `BootstrapDialog`'s `onshown:` callback function.